# Magento 2.3.5 admin login slow

Tags: magento2.3, admin, login

I updated to Magento 2.3.5-p2 and now the admin login takes forever, sometimes minutes. Is this a known problem? Tried to find some information on Google, but found nothing. Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Additional OS information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Review Installed Extensions (Remove Unused Modules, Optimize Utilized Ones)
2. Clean up Outdated, Unused, or Hidden Products and Categories
3. set Production Mode
4. php_value memory_limit 2048M
5. System > Configuration > Developer > JavaScript Settings > Merge JavaScript Files > Yes
6. php version check as per compitible
7. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
8. php bin/magento index:reindex
9. php bin/magento cron:remove

Comment: I did all of this ... nothing was changed except the Magento versin, so it cant really be any of those mentioned.

Comment: what is your php version

Comment: This generic optimization solution doesn't apply to the very specific "Magento admin *login* issue"